# Tagging in Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As hard as I try I can not find how to reference my tag in my CS file.

In my XAML file I have the following

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<TextBlock Text="User Id" Margin="30" Foreground="White" FontSize="25" />
<TextBox x:Name="logInUserIdText" IsSpellCheckEnabled="True" Height="40" Margin="13,1" Width="408"  InputScope="EmailSmtpAddress" FontFamily="Global User Interface" KeyDown="logInUserIdKeyDown" Tag="1" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<TextBlock Text="Password" Margin="20" Foreground="White"  FontSize="25" />
<PasswordBox  x:Name="logInPasswordText"  IsPasswordRevealButtonEnabled="True" Height="40" Margin="5,1"  Width="408"  KeyDown="logInPasswordKeyDown" Tag="2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now in my CS file I have the following

```
 private void logInUserIdKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
         logInUserIdString = logInUserIdText.Text;
         Debug.WriteLine("aa");
         logInPasswordText.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
     }

 }

 private void logInPasswordKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
         logInPasswordString = logInPasswordText.Password;
         Debug.WriteLine("bb");
     }
 }
```

And the issue is that regardless of which box is in focus, if I hit *ENTER* on the keyboard **both methods get fired** and the output is **aa bb** which are the debug statements in each method.

So I assume that since I set the tag value in XAML I should be able to do something like

```
if (e.Key == Virtual.Enter)&&(e.Tag == 1)
  Debug.WriteLine("loginuserid method only called");
```

But I can not, it wont let me reference the tag in the CS file.  Why not?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happen to you seems *impossible*. To inspect more closely, try to run your application in debug mode, put breakpoint at the beginning of both method. Then, when execution hit breakpoint, you can see which control trigger that event from `sender` parameter (I prefer to use visual studio watch window to see content of variable).

The same concept can be used to get `Tag` value :

```
var s = (FrameworkElement)sender;
var tagValue = (string)s.Tag;
```

But I suggest to fix the original problem rather than workaround it with using `Tag` value.

Comment: Yep agreed, I found that my code was working correctly and the line: logINpasswordText.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); was causing the logInPasswordKeyDown method to be called.  I am such a newbie and live on the kindness of folk at Stackoverflow.  Thanks heaps for your quick answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to know you found the root cause quickly :)